# MongoDb connection string problem - retryWrites Expected stringified boolean value

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-atlas

i have a problem with the connection to an Atlas cluster for mongoDB.

if i try to fetch some data it returns an error

> "No write concern mode named 'majority',' found in replica set configuration"

i've looked up the error and everybody says to delete the `&w=majority` at the end of the connection string.

did that but now i'm facing a new error

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoParseError: For retryWrites Expected stringified boolean value, got: true

I haven't modified the string in any way, it was working yesterday.

my string is

> mongodb+srv://username:password@cluster0.yummd.mongodb.net/dbName?retryWrites=true&w=majority

there's no white space or anything at the end of the string, dunno what it is.

any help?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and came across your post.
I found out that the problem in my connection was that i had  double and than single quotes`"'mongodb+srv://username:password@database.aaaa.mongodb.net/collection?retryWrites=true&w=majority'"`. So the simple solution was just to remove the single quotes. That fixed the issue for me. And then you get : `"mongodb+srv://username:password@database.aaaa.mongodb.net/collection?retryWrites=true&w=majority"`

I don't know if you have already solved it, but maybe you haven't.

Answer (score 0):

You have some non-printable characters in your URI. Type it out by hand without copy-pasting.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I haven't really modified it in any way. That string has been living on the .env file for the past few weeks

Comment: @ChristmasFighters How did you ended up fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

There can be two possible reasons:

1. The line `dotenv.config();` should be above `const MongoStore = connectMongo;`
2. Check `mongodburl` for spaces and characters

Comment: this was the case for me
I copied the string from Atlas and pasted it in VS code.
My formatter(Prettier) edited it while saving and added a linebreak and a blank space in it.
So i just saved my username and pswd in my .env file and used it in the uri.